# Spring Webflux and Observable responses not working

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, rx-java, spring-webflux

I just created a simple Spring Boot application using spring-boot-starter-webflux with version 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT which brings spring-webflux version 5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and same for Spring Core, Beans, Context, etc.

If I create a simple `@RestController` and provide a `@GetMapping` that simply returns a `Flux<String>`, then everything works as expected.

However, if I change from `Flux` to RxJava's `Observable`, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

Debugging a bit through the code I found that Jackson's `ObjectMapper` somehow registers `Flux`, `Mono` and the rest of reactive types in its typeFactory, so later the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` knows how to (de)-serialize them.

However, it's not the case when I use an `Observable`: I don't find the type `Observable` or `Single` registered in the `ObjectMapper`'s type factory, so I get the aforementioned error.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Am I missing any dependency? Do I need to manually tell Jackson how to (de)-serialize from RxJava constructs? But why does Jackson already know about Flux and Mono?

Thanks for your help.

**EDITED:**

I'm using RxJava 1.2.7. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- RxJava dependeencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And here is the example of my controller code:

```
/**
 * Get all the available tasks.
 *
 * @return the list of tasks
 */
@GetMapping(path = "/task")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Observable<TaskView> allTasks(@AuthenticationPrincipal LoggedUserVO principal) {
    return this.pocComponent.getAllTasks()
            .map(t -> ViewConverter.convertFromTaskDocument(t, principal));
}
```

Comment: Can you post your pom/gradle file? Which RxJava version are you using? Please also add some code like your controller.

Comment: I would remove the `version` as spring Boot already manages that, you would also need the `reactive-streams` extension for rxjava to make it integration with Reactive.io as the Reactive Streams are the integration point for the different reactive implementations.

Comment: If I remove the version for RxJava I get 1.1.8. The `reactive-streams` dependency (version 1.0.0) is transitively obtained through the dependency `spring-boot-starter-webflux`. In any case, still not working.

Comment: That is weird because when I look at the managed dependency that is 1.2.7... Is everything you use from Spring Boot 2.0.0??? Or have you just included this dependency into an existing older spring boot version? Or in short, can you add your full pom? You need the rxjava-reactive-streams dependency...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably missing the following dependency to make it works:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxjava-reactive-streams</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Changes in various RxJava 1.x versions made it challenging for us to support it out of the box, that's why we prefer to rely on the [official RxJava -> Reactive Streams adapter](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaReactiveStreams). Notice that RxJava 2.x is supported without requiring additional dependencies (it is natively built on top of Reactive Streams).

I am going to update [Spring WebFlux reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html) to specify this is required to have RxJava 1.x support.

Comment: Sébastien, I added that new dependency to my pom.xml, but still getting the same error. Also tried with RxJava2 without success. Could you point me to the code where you "register" the Observable type in Jackson so I can check whether it's actually done or not? Thanks.

Comment: So far using this workaround:
`private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
  ...
  JsonSerializer<?> s = new StdSerializer<Observable<?>>(Observable.class, true) {
   @Override
   public void serialize(
     Observable<?> obs, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider p
   ) throws IOException {
    provider.findValueSerializer(Iterator.class, null)
      .serialize(obs.blockingIterable().iterator(), jgen, p);
   }
  };
  om.registerModule(new SimpleModule("Observable API", Version.unknownVersion(), Arrays.asList(s)));

  return jackson;
 }`

Comment: OK I will have deeper a look today

Comment: I confirm it works as described in my answer, see this sample example https://github.com/sdeleuze/webflux-rxjava1. Could you have a look to your project and see what are the differences? Please make sure you are using `spring-boot-starter-webflux` and not `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Comment: I updated Spring WebFlux reference documentation with required dependencies detail https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/92288630cf987fee43a8ab14d0f2733fa91509fd.

Answer (score -7):

So, `Flux` and `Mono` are Spring names, as Spring has the Not-Invented-Here syndrome.

You can either register a handler that does the conversion to types that Spring knows about, use the AsyncResponse facility that Jersey provides, or add toBlocking everywhere.

Comment: But the official documentation from Spring clearly states that it supports also RxJava with Observable and Single. Although I cannot make it work.

Comment: Instead of trying to bash a framework you want to provide a constructive answer. (For as far as this could be considered an answer as it doesn't really answer the question).

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not bashing Spring, I'm using it everyday (and the easiest way to recognize the value that it adds is trying to use an inhouse framework after using spring) - I'm just stating that it has the tendency to duplicate concepts within its own namespace.

Comment: Which is bashing in my book. Also instead of making that comment you might want to check WHY there is reactive under the hood (there is a pretty good reason for it actually and it has nothing to do with not-invented-here).